# help on proving converging of sequence, please

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have $f(x)$.

I know this
$$|f'(x)|≤ C < 1 $$ $$0≤C$$ $$x ∈R$$

and I have this sequence
$$a_1=x\\ a_2=f(x)\\ a_3=f(f(x)),\\\vdots\\ a_n=f(\cdots(f(x))\cdots)$$

> I need to prove this sequence converge (monotonous and bounded)
>
> and $f(L)=L$, when $a_n = L$.

I proved that |f(x)-f(y)| ≤ C|x-y| for all x,y ∈R

Comment: Your "monoton[e] and bounded" comment is not right. The sequence certainly need not be monotone. Can you show it is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: I tried showing that it a Cauchy sequence, but i didn't succeed..

Comment: Here's the hint: Can you rewrite $|a_3-a_2|$ in a way that will allow you to use the information? What about $|a_4-a_3|$? Continue.

Comment: I wasn't able show it a cauchy sequence, I think I missing something...

Comment: What did you get for my two questions in the previous comment?

Comment: what if f(x)=-x ? this sequence is not monotone, so I don't know how to certainly say an+1>an

Comment: Forget about monotone. You need to use the last sentence of your question repeatedly.

Comment: that's what i missing, I know |f(x)-f(y)|<1 but nothing about |f(f(x))-f(x)|

Comment: Huh? Keep $C$ in there. Remember that $a_2=f(a_1)$ and $a_3=f(a_2)$. Work hard.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration This seems to be basically fixed point iteration, and the first bullet under properties should explain convergence.